# Robotframework: custom library method keyword cannot be found

Tags: python, pycharm, automated-tests, robotframework

I am trying to use a custom method for right clicking through robot framework. I defined the following class

```
from robot.api.deco import keyword
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from SeleniumLibrary import SeleniumLibrary

class ExtendedSeleniumLibrary(SeleniumLibrary):

    @keyword("Right Click")
    def Right_Click(self, xpath):
        driver = self._current_browser()
        actionChains = ActionChains(driver)

        element=driver.find_element_by_xpath(str(xpath))

        actionChains.context_click(element).perform()
```

and the test case:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary
Library  ExtendedSeleniumLibrary.ExtendedSeleniumLibrary
Resource  ./ProcessModeler.robot
Resource  ../../../../Code/test.robot
*** Variables ***
${ADD_BUTTON} =  //button[@menu="add-popupmenu"]
${CREATE_FOLDER} =  //a[contains(@data-selected-option,"ADD_FOLDER")]
${FRAME} =  //iframe[contains(@name,"processmodeler_")]
${FOLDER_TITLE} =  //*[@id="name"]
${SAVE_FOLDER} =  //button[@class="btn-modal btn-modal-primary hide-focus"]
${MAIN_FOLDER} = //span[text()=" AutomationTestFolder "]
*** Keywords ***

Folder tear down
    navigate to process designer
    wait until element is visible  ${FRAME}  180s
    select frame  ${FRAME}
    wait until element is visible  xpath=//span[text()=" AutomationTestFolder "]
    right click  xpath=//span[text()=" AutomationTestFolder "]
```

when I try to run the test I get the error `No keyword with name 'right click' found.`

the weird thing is that it looks like PyCharm finds the library and shows it to me in preview when coding:
[image]

I am very confused. Please help

Comment: We cannot reproduce this problem with the code you provided. Your test case file has no test cases, only keywords. There are also syntax errors. Also, it would help if your [mcve] didn't require any other libraries that aren't strictly necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom library file should be mentioned in the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

You can also run your test using the -P option. So, you would execute something like this from the command line

`robot -P /path/to/library/file.py /path/to/test/folder` also include any other option that you'd like